Solana Test Validator
root@ZJ-Kaizen:/# (when Use this in solave test validator ) it works here
root@ZJ-Kaizen:/mnt/c/Solana/Model1# (when Use this in solave test validator ) it not works here

My first guess would be that you didn't add solana to your path.
The second step in this guide https://solana.com/docs/intro/installation#install-the-solana-cli
